# How to create a hyperlink to a onedrive file or folder without sharing it with anyone - and then use it

Tags: onedrive

(Once the hyperlink is created I will use it in OneNote to link to a file on my own Onedrive, for only me to use !)

When I view a file in Word online the URL displayed is:

https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=53B31F7A44698440&resid=53B31F7A44698440%2130033&app=Word

Say I want to insert a link to the file in a website or OneNote page, such that it has NOT been shared with anyone.  ie Only I have permissions to view it like the file reference by the above link.

Can I simply use the above URL as a link?

I have used OneDrive sharing, but I think all the methods given result in the file being shared with other named people or publically.  eg like this one:

http://1drv.ms/1zOli6p

...which when viewed in word online shows this URL:

https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=53B31F7A44698440&resid=53B31F7A44698440%2130035&app=Word

I have been experimenting and using the URL seems to work.  However, if the above does work, what I don't get is why OneNote does not allow a link to be created to a file stored on Ondrive. (On my PC it sonly seems to allow links to locally stored files).

I have used GoogleDrive which allows you to select a  file and right click it to "receive a link" which you can use in the manner described above.  This is a really useful feature.

Note that in a similar way, I would like to create a link that causes onedrive to open and display a chosen folder.  This seems to work ok when I use a URL this one that only I have permissions to view:

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=53B31F7A44698440&id=53B31F7A44698440%2130031

Any advise is really appreciated.

Harvey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links you copy/paste from your browser's address bar should work just fine, as your experiments have confirmed. If you're not trying to share the content with other people, you don't need to go through the sharing flows. You can just use those URL's.

From within OneNote itself you can also get links to content by right-clicking on a page/section/notebook and clicking 'copy link to page,' 'copy link to section,' etc.

Comment: It's crazy that its not clearly "documented" in the ondrive GUI or in any help decumentation that I can find.

Comment: @HarveyFrench if you ask that because you'd like to see this feature implemented, SO is only a place to receive help; for product improvements you should use Microsoft Connect - https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-suggestions/office/

Comment: I did want help!  It should be easier to do this in Onedrive.  Gdrive is much more user friendly.  I don't think I will insult the MS team by requesting what is blindingly obvious functionality that is so well implemented by google.  There has got to be a good reason for MS onedrive not doing it - surely.  (Mind you they did create windows 8...Hmmm)

Comment: @daspek.  I've just realised you work for MS on onedrive.    You answer contains the word should.  I'd prefer it to have contained the word will.   I'm very surprised onedrive and dropbox don't allow users to easily get a link to a file.....with a nice option on a popup menu.  It's interesting how many views this question has had.

Comment: @HarveyFrench the design is that users can use/bookmark the URL in the address bar, as they'd expect on most websites. You only need to get a special link when you share an item with others. Are you suggesting that we implement an explicit "get link" action because you've been led to distrust the durability of the URL in the address bar? Or are you running into a situation where using the address bar URL is cumbersome?

Comment: I'd like onedrive to work like gdrive and provide an explicit get link option. This option would answer my original question as the interface explicitly describes the functionality. Some URLs to other sites are not persistent, how are users to know whether onedrive ones are or not.

Comment: Also, if I copy the url and email it to someone else will it allow them to open the document (if I've shared a link to the document with them?). Where are the help pages that describe the above. I couldn't find any that explained this clearly, fully or adequately, hence my original question!

Comment: Also consider using onedrive on android. How can I get a link to a doc for me to use in onenote? Sharing view only gives the world access to the file via a link (if they get our back the link). Sharing causes gives  of text as well as the url.

Comment: @HarveyFrench I talked this over with the team. Thank you for your feedback. These are very good points, and we're going to consider this as part of other improvements we're making to the UX.

Comment: I don't like that OneNote links to OneDrive files always open in a web browser and cause me to download a PDF file that I already have cached in my local OneDrive path.

Comment: @daspek: Yeah, I ended up here because I don't trust the browser urls and wanted to link to various files already shared with my team and don't like the idea of creating a world-sharable link. I still don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can open folder in OneDrive online (via browser or right clicking on the folder in File Explorer then selecting "view online") and click "get link"  at the top.  Just cut and paste into OneNote.  From there you can edit/rename the link as usual.

Oddly, OneNote has functionality to copy a FILE link using the Insert > Link, but you can't stop at the folder level.

Ideally, I'd like the above option as well as dragging a folder from OneDrive within Windows File Explorer and have it ask me if I want to copy the entire folder or create a link.

Comment: Captquin .. The good news is that Microsoft are listening and it would seem they have done what I suggested!

Comment: I'm not able to find a "Get Link" button. I only have "Open", "Share", "Download", "Embed" and others. Has it been removed again!?

Answer (score 0):

I use links in format
https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=fd5d9e0ac8248db7!3447 (example, not real link)
or
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=fd5d9e0ac8248db7!3447

where

fd5d9e0ac8248db7 - is your ID number, and
3447 - is ID number of element (folder, Word file, OneNote notebook, media etc.)

P.S. Link format for open .one files online and folders inside OneNote online:

https:/ /onenote.officeapps.live.com/o/onenoteframe.aspx?Fi=SDfd5d9e0ac8248db7!3447&H=emul&C=5_810_BN1-SKY-WAC-WSHI&ui=Ru-RU

(example, not real link)

where

https:/ /onenote.officeapps.live.com/o/onenoteframe.aspx?Fi=SD_____yourIDnumber___!___elementID____&H=emul&C=5_810_BN1-SKY-WAC-WSHI&ui=Ru-RU

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive has a "Copy link" function in a few places that you would think does what it states. However, as soon as you select "Copy link", a share is created with the defaults of your OneDrive (which could be your organisation's). In my case, the default is share with editing permissions. This is probably the last thing you would expect when you are requesting to "Copy link". This is really quite dangerous, since the now shared link could be used by anybody if it subsequently forwarded to others.

Why would you want to copy a link? My use case is that I have a folder shared as read only with specific people. I want to give them a link to a sub-folder or file that they already have access to, but I do not want to create new permissions, that in my case give editing to anybody with the link!

It seems that the way to properly "copy a link" (literally) is as suggested ie copy the URL from the address bar.